# External Email html blocked in script php if HTML

Tags: php, email, cpanel, html-email

Hello with this script if I uncomment the line `$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";`the server will not send email to external addresses (Internal yes). No errors in log or in console. No trace in exim

Ubunto Cpanel Whm. I tried with PHP 5.6 and 7.4 but same problem

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$to = 'xxxx@gmail.com,contact@xxx.com';
$subject = 'Test HTML Email';
$message = '<html><body><strong>Ceci est un test pour vérifier l\'envoi de courriels.</strong></body></html>';
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "From: contact@wxxx.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: contact@xxx.com\r\n";
//>>>>>>//$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo "Email envoyé avec succès à $to\n";
} else {
    echo "Échec de l'envoi de l'e-mail à $to\n";
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo "Erreur de mail : " . $error['message'] . "\n";
}
?>
```

I tied to search logs or exim trace but I found nothing. In my console I have just :

```
Échec de l'envoi de l'e-mail à xxxx@gmail.com,contact@xxxx.com
Erreur de mail :
```

If I put only internal mail it works

It's working fine with plain html but with html header and external emails nothing happen

Comment: Your mail server’s log should say what the problem is. Alternatively, switch to using PHPMailer, which you tagged this question with.

Comment: Sorry Synchro I deleted that tag I was searching Mailphp. In exim nothing happened no trace.  Hosting provider told me that he couldn't do anything if no error no trace

Comment: Question : After uncommenting the line you mentioned , if you send to other non-gmail email accounts (e.g. xxx@hotmail.com, xxx@yahoo.com), will the email arrive there ?

Comment: @KenLee it arrives only when there are only emaiks hosted on that account. If they are mixed with external ones even not gmail, nothing happens

Comment: mixed ? (so you use c.c. ?)

Comment: No comma but even with cc nothing happen if there is an external email